# Confusion with covariant derivatives with vielbeins

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, exterior-algebra, connections, exterior-derivative

I have some confusion regarding how the covariant derivative is defined for one forms on a manifold in the context of frames/vielbeins. I am a physics student and my reference is Sec 4.3 of the [Lectures on Advanced Mathematical Methods for Physicists](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789814299749_others01) by Sunil Mukhi. I have given the context behind my confusion below.

Suppose we have some notion of orthonormal frames $E_a = E_a^{~\mu}~\partial_{\mu}$ on an $n$ dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$. Here, the Greek indices are coordinate indices and the Latin indices are indices with respect to $O(n)$ which "rotates" the frame
$$E_a \to E'_a = M_a^{~b}~E_b~,$$
where $M_a^{~b} \in O(n)$.

Given such frames, one can also define "dual frames" $e^a = e^a_{~\mu}~dx^{\mu}$ such that $$\left<e^a,E_b\right> = \delta^a_{~b}$$

Now, suppose I have a one-form $A$ which has a coordinate representation $A = A_{\mu}~dx^{\mu}$. I can project this onto a frame of my choice to obtain $A_a = E_a^{~\mu}A_{\mu}$ which is a coordinate scalar but is still a vector under $O(n)$ i.e. $A_a \to A'_a = M_a^{~b}A_b$. If I now consider the exterior derivative, in the absence of the frames I have

$$dA = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}~dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}~,$$

which is a two-form under coordinate transformations. However, $dA$ no longer transforms covariantly under $O(n)$. Hence, one defines the covariant derivative:

$$(DA)_a = dA_a + \omega_a^{~b}A_b~,$$

where $\omega_a^{~b} = \left(\omega_a^{~b}\right)_{\mu}~dx^{\mu}$ is a one-form under coordinate transformations. Demanding that $DA'_a = M_{a}^{~b}\left(DA_b\right)$ then gives us that $\omega_a^{~b}$ must transform inhomogenously under $O(n)$. So far is clear to me.

However, if we consider the covariant derivative of the dual frame $e^a$, this is defined to be:

$$De^a = de^a + \omega^a_{~b}\wedge e^b $$

Why does the wedge product become important here but not in the previous case, since $A_a$ is also the projection of a one-form in our frame?

Comment: This is actually wrong. The covariant derivative of a coframe element should be a covariant tensor of order 2, but certainly not skew-symmetric.

Comment: @TedShifrin, could you please explain what you mean? My $De^a$ is meant to be a rank two tensor wrt coordinate transformations

Comment: If $De_a = \omega_a^b \otimes e_b$, then, covariantly differentiating $e^a(e_b)=\delta^a_b$, you should get $De^a = -\omega^a_b\otimes e^b$.